# Selecting <br/> in FOR XML PATH Query in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have written following SQL Query :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(
    SELECT  ', <br />'+  
    [tblSectors].[title]
     FROM tblSectors  WHERE 1=1  AND  sector_id IN 
     (SELECT sector_id FROM tRelBusinessSector WHERE business_id = 2517)
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CSV
```

it displays following output :  `&lt;br /&gt;Personal Injury, &lt;br /&gt;Financial products/services`

It doesn't display `<br/>` in the output ?? why ??

Comment: please don't output html from SQL :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ', <br />' + s.[title]
    FROM dbo.tblSectors s
    WHERE sector_id IN (
            SELECT sector_id
            FROM dbo.tRelBusinessSector
            WHERE business_id = 2517
        )
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
```

Comment: This works.  An explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing with the `'FOR XML PATH'` clause is doing a kind of 'hack' to concatenate strings in SQL. This clause can be used to generate an XML document, so any `<` `>` values will be replaced by the HTML escaped equivalent of the value.

Either create your own concatenation function with SQLCLR or parse the result on the client instead of writing it out here.